# Jquery find td with a specific value

Tags: jquery

I have a table and in each column of each row I have a different number as a value

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use Jquery to find the td with the value 1, I've tried with:

```
$('td[text="1"]')
$('td[html="1"]')
$('td[value="1"]')
```

But none of them is working, and if I use *contains* then I'll get the three of them which is not what I want.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.filter()` with its helper function signature,

```
var elems = $('td').filter(function(){
 return this.textContent.trim() === "1"
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kke78LL2/)

Comment: @Aldipa Glad to help! :)